# How to send a new random number with every request in locust?

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

I have a simple use case which i am trying to achieve. I basically want to pass a new random number in my URL with every request. It seems like its passing the same random number every time though.

```
class UserBehavior(SequentialTaskSet):


    @task
    def GETCall(self):

        seedValue = random.randrange(sys.maxsize)
        random.seed(seedValue)
        print("Seed was:", seedValue)
        num = random.randint(10, 500)
        print("Random Number", num)

       
with self.client.get("http://google.com?/waitfor=" + num,name="GET Request",headers=headers,catch_response=True) as response1:
if response1.status_code == 200:
                response1.success()
            else:
                response1.failure("Invalid code")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete these lines:

```
seedValue = random.randrange(sys.maxsize)
random.seed(seedValue)
print("Seed was:", seedValue)
```

(or if you must have them for some reason, only call then once, outside your task, maybe at top level)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that but i keep getting this error can only concatenate str (not "int") to str (this is when i try to append num variable to the url)

Comment: try replacing num = random.randint(10, 500) with num = str(random.randint(10, 500)) to make it a string

Comment: Thanks that fixed the issue! Seperate issue but is this the right way to check for multiple conditions if ((resp2.status_code == 200) and (resp2.text == "dummy123")):
                resp2.success()

Comment: you’d need to add else: resp2.failure(”oopsies”) to make it fail (otherwise any non-error response code would still be a success)